# Multiply strings?

Tags: java, android, string

So,i have those :

```
String[] pret = new String[allcant.size()];
String[] totaluri = new String[allcant.size()];
String[] cant = new String[allcant.size()];
```

I want to do something like this :

```
totaluri[l]=pret[l]*cant[l];`
```

but i can't.I guess i have to make them float? since my input from the edittexts that get the values in the cant and pret are decimals? How can i do that ? 
I tried this but it won't let me

```
totaluri[l]=Float.parseFloat(cant[l]) *Float.parseFloat(pret[l]);
```

Comment: Try using `Double.parseDouble()` to convert a `String` into a number which can be used for mathematical operations.

Comment: Tried this : totaluri[l] = Double.parseDouble(cant[l]) * Double.parseDouble(pret[l]);    It says i can't convert from double to string

Comment: The Java compiler doesn't know what's in your String -- specifically, whether it represents a number. What's "house" times "fi$!,kzie¥rzrs"?

Comment: @SorinGrecu I have provided a more detailed answer, including how to convert the number back to a String.

Comment: Why are you using floats? Very few good reasons to do that.  Your multiplication will be much less accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Double.parseDouble()` or `Float.parseDouble()` to convert a `String` to a numerical value with a decimal fraction. You can then use `Double.toString()` or `Float.toString()` to convert the result of your calculation back to a `String.

Putting this all together:

```
double temp = Double.parseDouble(cant[l]) * Double.parseDouble(pret[l]);
totaluri[l] = Double.toString(temp);
```

I strongly suggest that you read [Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) and [Lesson: Numbers and Strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/index.html) from Oracle's Java Tutorial for more information about using `String`s and Java's primitive data types.

Comment: +1 even though I doubt a `double` would make a good "total uri"

Comment: Thanks dude,i got it,this will help me a lot further ! Have a nice one !

Comment: Note: you are likely to want to round `temp` before converting back into a String.  Otherwise you can get rounding errors.

Comment: Uhm,and how can i do that ? sorry,a total beginner here..started learning like 5 days ago,no programming background.

Comment: @PeterLawrey The variable name probably should be something like `uriCount` instead...

Comment: @SorinGrecu Do you really need decimal places? From the name `totaluri`, I think you are trying to count something, which implies you are using only whole numbers. If so, you can modify my example by using `int` instead of `double` and `Integer.parseInt()` and `Integer.toString()`.

Comment: Totaluri is probably in Romanian and it means totals. Most likely nothing related to uri.

Comment: @SorinGrecu Since you are just starting out, I very strongly suggest that you start reading the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html). They explain these basic concepts very well. I linked the two relevant "trails" in my answer above.

Comment: @Voicu Thanks for the translation.

Comment: Thanks Voicu and Code-Guru.I'll read as much as i can.Well,totaluri is going to be decimal.Totaluri gathers a multiplication of 2 edittexts that are dynamically created.After i gather the totals i need,i'll add them in a final total.I don't know what uri is,hehe,guess it's too soon for me to know anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
BigDecimal pretBD = BigDecimal.valueOf(pret[i]);
BigDecimal cantBD = BigDecimal.valueOf(cant[i]);
BigDecimal totaluriBD = pretBD.multiply(cantBD).setScale(2);  // Decimals #.##

totaluri[i] = totaluriDB.toString();
```

It is much typing, and no operators (multiply, add), but `double` is for financial purposes inadequate. 5000 * 0.2 will not be 1000.0.

Answer (score -1):

What about this?

```
totaluri[l] = new String(Float.parseFloat(cant[l]) * Float.parseFloat(pret[l]));
```

Comment: The constructor String(float) is undefined

Comment: totaluri[1] = new Float(Float.parseFloat(cant[l]) * Float.parseFloat(pret[l])).toString();

Comment: `String` does not have any constructors which accept a `double` or a `float`. Check the API docs for `String`.